# jquery ui plugin for quartz.net cron format

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, quartz.net

I have been looking around, I wonder if some one has written or if there is a way to use this plug in with version 2 of quartz cron format?

http://shawnchin.github.io/jquery-cron/

Comment: Do you want to build cron expressions for Quartz.net? [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wan able to modify this plugin, and use it with quartz
http://www.arnapou.net/2012-07-jquery-cron/

Comment: I have tried updated plugin. Its giving me invalid cron expression with method getCron().

Comment: I made an easy hach like this to make it work:`Dim _cron As String = hf11.Value

   Dim words As String() = _cron.Split(New Char() {" "c})

   If words(4) = "*" Then
    words(4) = "?"
   ElseIf words(2) = "*" Then
    words(2) = "?"
   End If

   _cron = "0 " & String.Join(" ", words)`